# How use schemas of SQL Server with tds_ecto?

Tags: ecto, elixir

I have a model like this

```
defmodule AppRest.Category do 
  use AppRest.Web , :model 

  schema "ventas.categories" do 
    field :name, :string timestamps()
  end
end
```

when i use it in the controller, with Repo.all

```
def index(conn, _params) do 
  categories = Repo.all(Category) 

  render(conn, "index.json", categories: categories) 
end
```

it generate the query like this

```
SELECT g0.[id], g0.[name], g0.[inserted_at], g0.[updated_at] 
FROM [global.categories] AS g0
```

then SQL Server can't process the query and return this error:

> The object name 'Ventas.categories' is not valid.

The query in right format is like this

```
SELECT g0.[id], g0.[name], g0.[inserted_at], g0.[updated_at] 
FROM [global].[categories] AS g0`
```

So the question is how i can set the name of schema of the table of SQL Server, in the model?

I hope any can help me with this.

Comment: Can you try setting the `@schema_prefix`? Link to the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#module-schema-attributes)